# wordpress Ajax call to php function doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I've tried a bunch of different things but I just cannot get AJAX with Wordpress to work. I clearly don't get something but I do not know what it is.  Always get a result on admin-ajax.php  0

```
     public function enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery-3.3.1-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), "3.3.1", false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ). 'js/wp-public.js', __FILE__, array() , $this->version, true);
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array(
                'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')

                 )
       );

}
```

**wp-public.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
  {

    $(".like-btn, .dislike-btn").click(function()
      {
        var id = this.id; // Getting Button id
        var split_id = id.split("_");

        var text = split_id[0];
        var postid = split_id[1]; // postid

        // Finding click type
        var type = 0;
        if(text == "like-btn") {
          type = 1;
        }else {
          type = 0;
        }

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax(
          {
          url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            'action': 'my_action',
            postid: postid,
            type: type
            },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {

              $("#likes_"+postid).text(data.likes); // setting likes
              $("#unlikes_"+postid).text(data.unlikes); // setting unlikes
              $("#msg_"+postid).text(data.msg); // setting messages

              if (data.likes || data.unlikes > "") {

                if(type == 1) {
                  $("#like-btn_"+postid).css("color", "#0757fe");
                  $("#dislike-btn_"+postid).css("color", "#8e8e8e");
                }

                if(type == 0) {
                  $("#dislike-btn_"+postid).css("color", "#f1476e");
                  $("#like-btn_"+postid).css("color", "#8e8e8e");
                }

              }

            }
          }
        );

      }
    );
   }
);
```

included class

```
class Wp_Ahb_Content {

    public function __construct(   ) {
      add_action('wp_ajax_my_action','my_action');
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action','my_action');
    }

 function my_action() {
    global $wpdb;
    $whatever = $_POST['postid'] ;
    echo "postid".$whatever;
}
```

Variables were sent successfully without reply
**Screenshots**
[ajax response][1]
[ajax_object][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlmJ7.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO5i9.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

My_action function is not running
JUST Delete **add_action** from __construct () and add them to loader

```
add_action ('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

And I became as follows: ON **private function define_public_hooks()**

```
 $this-> loader-> add_action ("wp_ajax_my_action", $ plugin_public, "ajax_object");
```

```
$this-> loader-> add_action ("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action", $ plugin_public, "ajax_object");
```

It became operational
I just wanted to clarify, because I found a lot of questions
 regarding the **Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate**

Comment: For reference it's also helpful to use ```wp_die();``` at the end of your action.  In certain instances it may be required to return the proper response.